# Cosine similarity of representation of sentences formed with word vectors now measure word order?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning

I know, the original cosine similarity, when applied to representation of two documents by frequency of specific words, do not measure word order. I now see a whole bunch of papers applying cosine similarity to representation of pairs of sentences formed by words vectors. I assume they flatten the token# x embedding length matrix of each sentence to a long vector whose length is token# x embedding length of the original sentence. So "I love you" and "you love me(normalized to "I") would not yield 1 in this new way of applying cosine similarity whereas the old way would yield 1. Am I correct? Thanks for any enlightening answer.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly!

> "I love you" and "you love me(normalized to "I") would not yield 1 in this new way of applying cosine similarity whereas the old way would yield 1.

this modification is done:

> A slight modification is made for sentence
>   representation. Instead of using indexing words from a text collection, a set of words
>   that appear in the sentence pair is used as a feature set. This is done to reduce the
>   degree of data sparseness in sentence representation
>
> The standard TF-IDF similarity
>   (simTFIDF,vector) is defined as cosine similarity between vector representation of two
>   sentences.

you can read more [here](http://www.cis.drexel.edu/faculty/thu/research-papers/dawak-547.pdf)